# How to search for specific files in exact multiple folders? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-search

When searching in Windows 7, if I use this syntax in directory C:

```
type:="File Folder" name:="10 DOC" +type:="File" name:=".docx"
```

In which I have many folders named "10 DOC" in different parent folders.
So if I use the syntax above, do I get the ".docx" files from all folders named "10 DOC" in C: ?

Comment: You said you're using that syntax already so shouldn't you be aware of whenever it's finding all the files you expect it to?

Comment: I done searching and no results shown, maybe something is wrong but I want to make sure that this is correct or not. Well... it should be wrong so I need help to make it correct.